# How to unset array in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, unset

In bash shell for variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset

my_var=aaa
unset var
echo "$var"
```

Because `set` command is defined to return error if variable is not set, last line returns error:

> line 6: var: unbound variable

OK, that is what I want.

Now the same thing with arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset

my_array=(aaa bbb)
unset my_array
echo "${my_array[@]}"
```

But to my surprise last line does not return error. I would like bash script to return error when array is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${my_array[@]}` is similar to `$@` which is documented to be ignored by `nounset`:

> `-u`      Treat unset variables and parameters other than the special parameters  "@" and  "*"  as an error when performing parameter expansion.  If expansion is attempted on an unset variable or parameter, the shell prints an error message, and, if not interactive, exits with a non-zero status.

Returning the array size is not ignored, though. Prepend the following line to make sure the array is not unset:

```
: ${#my_array[@]}
```

Comment: This seems consistent with the observed behavior, but where is it documented that the `${my_array[@]}` form has this property?

Comment: Prior to Bash 4.4 `"${my_array[@]}"` produced an error when the array was defined but empty and `nounset` was set.  That was a bug.  It looks like they over-compensated when they fixed the empty array problem in 4.4.  I think the new behaviour is a bug.  It's not so bad a bug because there are several holes in the `nounset` checks anyway.

Comment: What does "colon" means before command?

Comment: Colon is a builtin that does nothing, see `man bash`.

Comment: It is something similar like:
**true  ${#my_array[@]}**
but ":" is shell build in and true is separate program.